# Problem with Dokka documentation for specific android classes

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-dokka, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

could you help with gradle, please?

I need to generate documentation only for com.example.kmpcorelib.repo package. Because now I generate all of project and not only classes in repo package.

```
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask>().configureEach {
    outputDirectory.set(rootDir.resolve("documentationForKMP"))
    dokkaSourceSets {
        configureEach {
            perPackageOption {
                matchingRegex.set("repo.*") // will match all .internal packages and sub-packages
                suppress.set(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```